# Getting: 500 OOPS: vsftpd: error with vsftpd.conf file that used to work

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I recently reinstalled Bionic at 18.04.4 because I was experiencing a lot of glitchy errors that were getting worse over time.  I had upgraded (not reinstalled) from Xenial which was probably a mistake.

Anyway, I can't seem to get vsftpd working.  I just use it for anonymous uploads to /srv/ftp

That directory has two subdirectories:
incoming
pub

"pub" is set up to be only readable, "incoming" is readable and writable.  I used the exact same vsftpd.conf file I had that was working before, but now I'm getting the error message in my subject line.  What did I forget?  Everything I've read on this error implies I need to add an additional line:
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

But that line wasn't present before.  I tried adding it and recycling vsftpd and it didn't make any difference.  HELP!  I'm sure I'm missing something simple and stupid here...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  For some reason, a userid was not created for vsftpd.  Once I defined one, it started working.  Weird.